# Why doesn't Psychlo breathe-gas explode in the bottle?

Tags: l-ron-hubbard, battlefield-earth

I am reading Battlefield Earth by L. Ron Hubbard. Part of the story centers around Psychlo breathe-gas being highly reactive to radiation. During one scene of the book MacTyler rides Windsplitter around a field with tactical nuclear mines in it with an open bottle of breathe-gas. The breathe-gas ignites when he is near a source of radiation.

What prevents the breathe-gas from reacting in its bottle or storage containers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "bottle" is metal, and blocks the radiation.

The breath gas in the scene where Johnny marks the location of the mines doesn't really ignite or explode.  It "sparkles." The mines are old and pretty much collapsed to dust and clumps under the ground, and didn't contain large amounts of uranium to begin with.

Dirt, and also air, block radioactivity to some extent.  Add the metal of the bottle, and there's not enough energy to set off breath gas.

---

Also remember that Hubbard a much better huckster than he is a physicist.

Uranium wouldn't lose an appreciable amount of radioactivity from the time the mines were installed until the time the story takes place.

So, in actual fact, the mines would be more dangerus in Johnny's time than when they were new.  The enclosures have broken and rusted away, removing the shielding they would have had when new.

Weathering wouldn't have had much effect on it either.

Comment: "Also remember that Hubbard a much better huckster than he is a physicist." - I know. He gets quite a bit wrong about firearms that actually existed and he gets it wrong in a way that wasn't necessary to the story. I read LRH because sometimes you want to listen to the drunk jerk at the bar tell about how is tour of duty in the Korean war helped him in the Iraq war. Its not true, good, wholesome, ethical, or nice but it is entertaining.

Comment: Yeah, well.  Wait until you get to the point where Johnny destroys Psychlo.  You will learn that the good old US of A managed to build indestructable atomic bombs that can survive the detonation of other atomic bombs at point blank range.   Still, its fun to read.